# Login using database authentication

Tags: c#, authentication

```
namespace Project
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        OleDbConnection MyCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Project.accdb");

        public string user;
        string password;
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            user = textBox1.Text;
            char firstLetter = user[0];
            string password = textBox2.Text;
            MyCon.Open();
            string command = "Select Name from Login where userid=@userid AND password = @password";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, MyCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@user, textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@password, textBox2.Text);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int id = cmd.Parameters[0].Value; // This line genrating error
          //  MessageBox.Show(user);
            if (firstLetter == 'E' )
            {
                if (dr.Read() == true )
                {

                    Window1 w1 = new Window1();
                    w1.textBox3.Text = user;
                    w1.textBox4.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                    w1.Show();
                    this.Close();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("NOt Login");    

                    }
                }
```

How do I retrieve id and then match id and password to user login? My Code has problems. If I give wrong id  but correct password then user can login. This does not happen if id and password are both wrong; user cannot Login..

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@user, textBox1.Text);
```

this line should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@userid, textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check that yor sqldatareader has row?

```
if (dr.HasRow){
 if (dr.Read())//Read Method Return a bool type
 {
  //Your Code
 }
}
```